# When is Chebyshev's $\vartheta(x)>x$?

Tags: number-theory, chebyshev-function

Various bounds and computations for Chebyshev's functions
$$
\vartheta(x) = \sum_{p\le x} \log p, \quad \psi(x) = \sum_{p^a\le x} \log p
$$
can be found in e.g.

- Rosser and Schoenfeld, *[Approximate Formulas for Some Functions of Prime Numbers](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-6/issue-1/Approximate-formulas-for-some-functions-of-prime-numbers/10.1215/ijm/1255631807.full)*
- Dusart, *[Estimates of Some Functions Over Primes without R.H.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.0442)*
- Nazardonyavi and Yakubovich, *[Sharper estimates for Chebyshev’s functions $\vartheta$ and $\psi$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.7208)*

Nazardonyavi and Yakubovich cite Ingham to give as Theorem 1.14
$$
\psi(x)-x = \Omega_{\pm}\left(x^{1/2}\log\log\log x\right)
$$
and [Wikipedia cites Hardy and Littlewood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function#Properties) already with
$$
\psi(x)-x \neq o\left(x^{1/2}\log\log\log x\right)
$$
(though it doesn't say explicitly that large deviations should be on both sides, but follows the two-sided result of Schmidt). These suggest that there should be infinitely many $x$ with $\psi(x)-x>A\sqrt{x}$ for any given constant $A$.

But Dusart gives for all $x>0$
$$
\psi(x)-\vartheta(x)<1.00007\sqrt{x}+1.78\sqrt[3]{x}
$$
which is bounded by a constant multiple of $\sqrt{x}$.

Hence (if I read correctly) there should be infinitely many $x$ with $\vartheta(x)>x$. Is any such value for $x$ known, or a range where this is expected to occur?

Comment: Some more estimates on $\theta(x)$ are given [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.7208); also $\theta(x)>0.99871149x$ for all $x\ge 10^8$, which is of course not what you have asked, but interesting.

Comment: Do the numbers represented in decimal notation represent exact rational numbers or floating point approximations to numbers of unknown algebraicity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Littlewood’s oscillation theorem says that there is a positive constant $C$ such that for infinitely many numbers $x$, 
$$
\theta(x) > x + C\sqrt{x}\log \log \log x.
$$
A discussion about this can be found in the article [Efficient prime counting and the Chebyshev primes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6489). It is related to the study of $\epsilon(x)=\mathrm{Li}(x)-\pi(x)$, and $\epsilon_{\theta(x)}=\mathrm{Li}(\theta(x))-\pi(x)$. The function $\epsilon(x)$ is known to be positive up to the very large Skewes’ number. On the other hand it is known that RH is equivalent to the fact that $\epsilon_{\theta(x)}$ is always positive. Concerning $\theta$ see also Lemma $1.6$ in the above article for $\theta(p_{n+1})>p_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 5):

The analogous problem of finding an explicit number $x$ where $\pi(x) > \mathop{\rm li}(x)$ is related to "[Skewes' number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewes'_number#More_recent_estimates)". For that problem, Bays and Hudson show that such an $x$ can be found less than about $1.4\times10^{316}$; this has been modestly improved a few times since then (I think most recently by [Zegowitz](http://eprints.ma.man.ac.uk/1547/01/covered/MIMS_ep2010_102.pdf)). Based on approximate computations, it seems reasonable to suspect that that's actually the size of the smallest such $x$.

People don't seem to have looked as much at specific $x$ for which $\theta(x)>x$, but the same techniques apply, and I suspect that the smallest such occurrence is basically the same as that of $\pi(x) > \mathop{\rm li}(x)$.